# Laravel Mix HMR not updating after compiling

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix

I have Laravel Mix 4.0.13 installed.

`npm run watch` works great, and running `npm run hot` it does seem to compile and detect my changes, recompiling.

However, nothing changes in the browser. In the console I see:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

And after compiling, I get the following message twice, every time I compile:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
```

I assume there needs to be another message that says `reloading` or something?

Another strange thing, if I try to refresh the page, it never loads anything from `localhost:8080`. It just sits there waiting indefinitely. I have to restart `npm run hot` and then reload the page.

Both JS/Vue and SASS doesn't reload in the browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably use `.version()` in your mix file.
Like in the docs, versioning in development is not very useful, so you could;

```js
if (mix.inProduction()) {
  mix.version();
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: Last night, I was checking everything worked fine. I used git to mark where it worked. but IDK why I committed with `version`. reverting to those versions didn't work until I reach this question and answers -_- Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a problem with `mix.version()`. After removing `.version()` from my webpack.mix.js file, everything appears to work.

Comment: I am sure it's inappropriate to say but FML -_-

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe file is in different case, like 'element.vue' or 'Element.vue'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include manifest.js in the page